# Get featured event using EventBrite API

Tags: eventbrite

How can I show Featured event by organization using Eventbrite API in PHP ? 
I have checked http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/ .Here in status parameter I can send live status for live events , but if there is more that one Event then any how  can I identify Featured Event out of so many events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is currently not possible via the API.  If you're working with your own account, you can take the event id of your featured event and use the event_get API:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/